# Not able to solve 'Title" has not been initialized

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I am attempting to disable the ability of a user to delete any attachments associated with the current record when they are in edit mode.  I found this code on [Sharing to the Point](https://sharingtothepoint.blogspot.com/2015/04/how-to-prevent-users-from-deleting.html?_sm_au_=isVn8DttR3NS13VM).  I had to make some changes just for it to run.  I think my problem now is that my dependent scripts are not loaded correctly and so the function is erroring out.  The code is:

```
//if (document.referrer == "" || document.referrer == null) 
if (window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().indexOf("editform.aspx") > -1) {
   // These two lines are required, without it my code won't run.
   SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext');
   SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.runtime.js');

   var listName = "BSMRequests"; 
   var currentItemID;
   var attachmentAuthor = [];
   var itemArray = [];
 
   $(document).ready(function(){  
      // Get ID of the current item.
      currentItemID = window.location.href.toLowerCase();
      currentItemID = currentItemID.substring(currentItemID.toLowerCase().indexOf("?id=") + 4,currentItemID.toLowerCase().indexOf("&source="));
      // Remove the line below in case the URL of your item is 
      // not shown as a modal dialog.
      //currentItemID = currentItemID.substring(0, currentItemID.toLowerCase().indexOf("&isdlg"));
      //console.log('currentItemID='+currentItemID);
  
      // Save the ID of the current item in the session 
      // (not necessary, but I prefer it this way)
      sessionStorage.setItem("SessionItemCurrentItemID", currentItemID);
 
      // Get attachments of current item.
      var url = "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('" + listName + "')/Items(" + currentItemID + ")/AttachmentFiles",
         qs = "?$select=ID,Author/Title,*&$expand=Author,AttachmentFiles",
         siteUrl = "https://share.health.wisconsin.gov/hc/teams/MES";
      $.ajax( {
         url : siteUrl + url + qs,
         type : 'GET',
         headers : {
            'accept' : 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'content-type' : 'application/json;odata=verbose'
         },
         success : successHandler,
         fail : failHandler
      });  
 
      function successHandler(data) {
         if (data) {
         // If the item has attachments, then run this function.
               //console.log('yes? attachments');
            $.each(data.d.results, function() {
               //console.log('processing results');
               getWebProperties(sessionStorage.getItem("SessionItemCurrentItemID"));
            });
         } //else {console.log('No attachments');}
      }
 
      function failHandler(data, errCode, errMessage) { 
         console.log('Error: ' + errMessage); 
      }
   
      function getWebProperties(itemID) {
         var attachmentFiles;
         var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
         var web = ctx.get_web();
         var attachmentFolder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Lists/'+listName+'/Attachments/' + itemID);
         attachmentFiles = attachmentFolder.get_files();
         ctx.load(attachmentFiles);
         ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
            // I can't remember what the $2_1 was again, but anyway...
            for (var j = 0; j < attachmentFiles["$2_1"].length; j++) {
               var author = attachmentFiles.itemAt(j).get_author(); 
               attachmentAuthor.push([attachmentFiles.itemAt(j).get_name(),author]);
   
               // You'll need to load the author along with the title parameter,
               // in order to be able to fetch the name of the author later.
               ctx.load(author, 'Title');
               ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){}, function(err) {});
            }
            // Loop is not necesarrily required, but you will need to set a
            // timeout. Comes in handy when you have a lot of attachments.
            checkAttachmentsLoop();
         }, function(err) {});
      }
   
      function checkAttachmentsLoop() {
         setTimeout(function(){
            if (attachmentAuthor.length) {
               checkAttachments();
            }
            else {
               checkAttachmentsLoop();
            }
         },100);
      }
   
      function checkAttachments() {
         for (var h = 0; h < attachmentAuthor.length; h++) {
            // if you log attachmentAuthor[h][0] to the concole, you'll get 
            // the name of the attachment.
            // if you log attachmentAuthor[h][1].get_title() to the console,
            // you'll get the name of the author.
    
            var currentAuthor = attachmentAuthor[h][1].get_title();
            // If the current user is not the author of the current attachment,
            // then we disable the ability to delete the attachment from the item.
            // var currentUser = "Harvancik, Steve Skkk";
            var currentUser = sessionStorage.getItem("sessionItemUserName");
            if (currentAuthor != currentUser) {
               var tr = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
               for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                  var currentTR = $(tr)[i];
                  var anchors = $(currentTR).find("a")[0];
                  var deletes = $(currentTR).find("a")[1];
                  if (anchors.innerHTML == attachmentAuthor[h][0]) {
                     $(currentTR).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                     $(anchors).css("color", "#b1b1b1");
                     $(anchors).removeAttr("href");
                     $(anchors).removeAttr("onclick");
                     $(deletes).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
                     $(deletes).css("color", "#b1b1b1");
                     $(deletes).removeAttr("href");
                     $(deletes).removeAttr("onclick");
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   })
}
else {
   if (sessionStorage.getItem("SessionItemCurrentItemID") != null) {
      sessionStorage.removeItem("SessionItemCurrentItemID");
   }
}
```

The errors I get are of the type:

```
Uncaught Error: The property or field 'Title' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
```

I first attempted to put it into a function and call it via ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded but that didn't work.  What is the best way to call this function and load the dependent scripts prior to running?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `author` you push to `attachmentAuthor` before  `ctx.executeQueryAsync`, so the value not loaded yet, you could load it in `checkAttachments`.

Test script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //if (document.referrer == "" || document.referrer == null)
        if (window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().indexOf("editform.aspx") > -1) {
            // These two lines are required, without it my code won't run.
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext');
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.runtime.js');

            var listName = "MyList";
            var currentItemID;
            var attachmentAuthor = [];
            var itemArray = [];

            $(document).ready(function () {
                // Get ID of the current item.
                currentItemID = window.location.href.toLowerCase();
                currentItemID = currentItemID.substring(currentItemID.toLowerCase().indexOf("?id=") + 4, currentItemID.toLowerCase().indexOf("&source="));
                // Remove the line below in case the URL of your item is
                // not shown as a modal dialog.
                //currentItemID = currentItemID.substring(0, currentItemID.toLowerCase().indexOf("&isdlg"));
                //console.log('currentItemID='+currentItemID);

                // Save the ID of the current item in the session
                // (not necessary, but I prefer it this way)
                sessionStorage.setItem("SessionItemCurrentItemID", currentItemID);

                // Get attachments of current item.
                var url = "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('" + listName + "')/Items(" + currentItemID + ")/AttachmentFiles",
                    qs = "?$select=ID,Author/Title,*&$expand=Author,AttachmentFiles",
                    siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
                $.ajax({
                    url: siteUrl + url + qs,
                    type: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                        'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
                    },
                    success: successHandler,
                    fail: failHandler
                });

                function successHandler(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        // If the item has attachments, then run this function.
                        //console.log('yes? attachments');
                        $.each(data.d.results, function () {
                            //console.log('processing results');
                            getWebProperties(sessionStorage.getItem("SessionItemCurrentItemID"));
                        });
                    } //else {console.log('No attachments');}
                }

                function failHandler(data, errCode, errMessage) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + errMessage);
                }

                function getWebProperties(itemID) {
                    var attachmentFiles;
                    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                    var web = ctx.get_web();
                    var attachmentFolder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Lists/' + listName + '/Attachments/' + itemID);
                    attachmentFiles = attachmentFolder.get_files();
                    ctx.load(attachmentFiles);
                    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                        // I can't remember what the $2_1 was again, but anyway...
                        for (var j = 0; j < attachmentFiles["$2_1"].length; j++) {
                            var author = attachmentFiles.itemAt(j).get_author();
                            attachmentAuthor.push([attachmentFiles.itemAt(j).get_name(), author]);                            
                        }
                        // Loop is not necesarrily required, but you will need to set a
                        // timeout. Comes in handy when you have a lot of attachments.
                        checkAttachmentsLoop();
                    }, function (err) { });
                }

                function checkAttachmentsLoop() {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        if (attachmentAuthor.length) {
                            checkAttachments();
                        }
                        else {
                            checkAttachmentsLoop();
                        }
                    }, 100);
                }

                function checkAttachments() {
                    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                    for (var h = 0; h < attachmentAuthor.length; h++) {
                        // if you log attachmentAuthor[h][0] to the concole, you'll get
                        // the name of the attachment.
                        // if you log attachmentAuthor[h][1].get_title() to the console,
                        // you'll get the name of the author.

                        // You'll need to load the author along with the title parameter,
                        // in order to be able to fetch the name of the author later.
                        ctx.load(attachmentAuthor[h][1], 'Title');
                        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                            var currentAuthor = attachmentAuthor[h][1].get_title();
                            console.log(currentAuthor);
                        }, function (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                        //var currentAuthor = attachmentAuthor[h][1].get_title();
                        // If the current user is not the author of the current attachment,
                        // then we disable the ability to delete the attachment from the item.
                        // var currentUser = "Harvancik, Steve Skkk";
                        var currentUser = sessionStorage.getItem("sessionItemUserName");
                        if (currentAuthor != currentUser) {
                            var tr = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
                            for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                                var currentTR = $(tr)[i];
                                var anchors = $(currentTR).find("a")[0];
                                var deletes = $(currentTR).find("a")[1];
                                if (anchors.innerHTML == attachmentAuthor[h][0]) {
                                    $(currentTR).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                                    $(anchors).css("color", "#b1b1b1");
                                    $(anchors).removeAttr("href");
                                    $(anchors).removeAttr("onclick");
                                    $(deletes).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
                                    $(deletes).css("color", "#b1b1b1");
                                    $(deletes).removeAttr("href");
                                    $(deletes).removeAttr("onclick");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            if (sessionStorage.getItem("SessionItemCurrentItemID") != null) {
                sessionStorage.removeItem("SessionItemCurrentItemID");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: I changed my code to what I thought you had in specific moved the author load and the query from geWebProperties to the check attachments.  I had to declare currentAuthor in the beginning (since I use it elsewhere and added the code, but got error message: Cannot read property '1' of undefined.  my code is for the ctx.load and executeQuery is exactly what you have.